# how to translate this block of code to javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to port this code into javascript to support my backend validation. however, I am not sure if javascript has any or isdigit() or comprehension lists in order to achieve this

```
def clean_password1(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
    special_characters = "[~\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+{}\":;,'\[\]]"

    if not any(char.isdigit() for char in password1):
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            'Password must contain at least %(min_length)d digit.' % {'min_length': 2})

    if not any(char.isalpha() for char in password1):
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            'Password must contain at least %(min_length)d letter.' % {'min_length': 6})

    if not any(char in special_characters for char in password1):
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            'Password must contain at least %(min_length)d special character.' % {'min_length': 1})

    if len(password1) < 8:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            'Password must contain at least %(min_length)d characters.' % {'min_length': 8})
```

javascript

```
if (password.length < 8){
  addErrorTo('password', data['message']['password1']);
}
```

Comment: No list comprehensions in JavaScript but the logic is straightforward enough to implement it using standard features. `isNaN` can check if a character is an **in**valid digit (`true` for invalid, `false` for valid). You might need a simple regex for letters. In general, you can just implement this with 3 regexes and a length check. Or even more generic, run through a regex (4 in total) for each check. Even then, if you're doing this in the UI, there are many validation libraries available which support standard. There are solutions for even password validation specifically.

Comment: `typeof char === 'number'` will check if it's a digit

Comment: @fedesc it's also never going to say `true`, since each character in a string is a string itself, never a number. Unless you convert it.

Answer (score 0):

- `Number.isInteger` checks the input if its a number or not. But input must be a number so `parseInt(char)` first http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isinteger.asp
- For isAlpha you can use a regex to test the string.
- For special characters you can use `special_characters.includes(targetChar)`

Comment: `str = "1abc"; Number.isInteger(str[0]) //false`

Comment: Yeah you need to use parseInt before

Answer (score 0):

Here is a check password function that will throw error or return true, you can remove all error throw and replace with a return false if you want.
That should help you.
(Not tested, not even made in an IDE, just fast made here for you)

```js
function checkPassword(pw="") {
    const special_characters = "[~\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+{}\":;,'\[\]]"
    pw=pw.split("")
    if (pw.length < 8)
        throw new Error("Password Length")
    if (!pw.some(c => special_characters.includes(c)))
        throw new Error("No special char")
    if (!pw.some(c => (c.charCodeAt(0) > 47 && c.charCodeAt(0)) < 58))
        throw new Error("No number")
    if (!pw.some(c => ((c.charCodeAt(0) > 64 && c.charCodeAt(0) < 91) || (c.charCodeAt(0) > 96 && c.charCodeAt(0) < 123))))
        throw new Error("No letter")
    return true
}
```